# Loop through images not working

Tags: php, html, list, loops, foreach

With this code, the ID is always 1. I want it to add +1 for each times it loops through the messages.

Like ex1, ex2 ex3 etc. etc.

I cant figure it out whats wrong. Could anyone help?

```
foreach ($message['attachment'] as $attachment)
{
    if ($attachment['is_image'])
    {
        if ($attachment['thumbnail']['has_thumb'])
            echo '<a href="', $attachment['href'], ';image" id="link_', $attachment['id'], '" onclick="', $attachment['thumbnail']['javascript'], '"><img src="', $attachment['thumbnail']['href'], '" alt="" id="thumb_', $attachment['id'], '" border="0" class="opplastetbilde"/></a><br />';

        else
            $id = 1;

        if ($id < 10) {
            echo '<span class="zoom" id="ex' . $id . '"><img src="' . $attachment['href'] . ';image" alt="" width="' . $attachment['width'] . '" height="' . $attachment['height'] . '" border="0" class="opplastetbilde"/></span><br />';
            $id++;
        }
    }

    echo '<a href="' . $attachment['href'] . '"><img src="' . $settings['images_url'] . '/icons/clip.gif" align="middle" alt="*" border="0" />&nbsp;' . $attachment['name'] . '</a> (', $attachment['size'], ($attachment['is_image'] ? ', ' . $attachment['real_width'] . 'x' . $attachment['real_height'] . ' - ' . $txt['attach_viewed'] : ' - ' . $txt['attach_downloaded']) . ' ' . $attachment['downloads'] . ' ' . $txt['attach_times'] . '.)<br />';
}
```

Comment: Please improve your coding style!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Its not like this in my editor.

Comment: You're concatenating string with commas (`,`). I don't think this does work in PHP, does it?

Answer (score 1):

move this before foreach or it is always reinitialize `$id`

```
$id = 1;
foreach ($message['attachment'] as $attachment)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're setting `$id = 1` each time you loop through the array

```
foreach ($message['attachment'] as $attachment) {
    // ...
    $id = 1;
    // ...
}
```

In order to increment it properly, you need to place it before the loop

```
$id = 1;
foreach ($message['attachment'] as $attachment) {
    // ...
}
```